# Install 32 bit Canopy on Win 7, 32-bit machine fails

Tags: python, installation, enthought, canopy

I'm trying to install Canopy (canopy-1.1.0-win-32.msi) on a 32 bit windows machine.   The install appears to work fine, but when I launch any of the tools, nothing happens.  I can open a command line and run canopy_cli.exe which I found and it claims that I used the wrong installer.   I've done it twice.   It is a 32-bit Dell Inspiron.  I've removed all Python related content from the system to try to get to a clean base.

Ideas?

Thx,
    --Don

Answer (score 0):

Existing PYTHONHOME and/or PYTHONPATH environment variables may be interfering with Canopy startup. For details, please see:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/22508619-Windows-Canopy-shortcut-in-Start-menu-doesn-t-do-anything